# Objective-C deselectRowAtIndexPath is kinda working

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath and I pre selecting a row:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [[communityPrefs objectForKey:@"Community"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *tempArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];

if ([tempArrayMutable containsObject:cell.textLabel.text])
{
    [selectedAreaTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

}
```

This part works great. However the selected item is at the bottom of the page and the user will not see it, but when they scroll down to that cell it is selected.

Now I am trying to write a piece of code the will deselect all selected cells like so:

```
for(NSIndexPath *index in selectedAreaTable.indexPathsForSelectedRows)
        {
            if(index.row != 0)
            {
                [selectedAreaTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:NO];
            }
        }
```

but after I run this code the cell at the bottom is still selected. So my question is, why is this cell not being deselected? Is it because its not there until you scroll to it? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: how are you testing? what is the index path when it doesn't work? how many index paths are in `indexPathsForSelectedRows`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because its not there until you scroll to it?

Yes. I believe that you should change "selected" state using cell objects only for visible rows. All other rows should retrieve "selected" status in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: selection is tracked by the table view, hence `indexPathsForSelectedRows`, not by the cells. selection is only displayed by the cells

Comment: I mean that you use `indexPathsForSelectedRows` for handle selection on _visible_ rows only (sorry if my explain was short and bad). You can not receive with this method indexPath's for rows that was not displayed yet (last row for example). So, you need to take care about it dynamically in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (since author use it from start), always performing actual selection state

Answer (score 0):

user979331,

you dont have to remove the selection in seperate method rather you can handle that too in cellForRowAtIndexPath as well.

1. You can declare the array NSMutableArray *tempArrayMutable as a property,
2. when you want to deselect all cell lets assume a method named clear all selection

   `-(void)clearAllSelection {
           [self.tempArrayMutable removeAllObjects];
           self.tableView reloadData];
   }`
3. Finally in cellForRowAtIndexPath change as

   `if ([self.tempArrayMutable containsObject:cell.textLabel.text])
   {
       [selectedAreaTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   }
   else{
       [selectedAreaTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
   }`